# How can i share ServiceContract.dll and Data.dll between WCF and MVC

Tags: c#, wcf, model-view-controller, shared

I am trying to establish a solution which contains `MVC` and `WCF`...  MVC will get the datas from WCF web service. WCF has Entity Framework and it will deploy the SQL datas in Data Transfer Objects (DTO) clases before send and after send it to  MVC solutions.

I want to do that : When I  add new webservice functions or update something in webservice, I will build the WCF service solution, and  WCF will deploy the new changes in `Company.XXXX.Shared.Data.dll` and `Company.XXXX.Shared.ServiceContracts.dll`

After this i will move this dlls to `C:\inetpub\wwwroot\myweb\bin` to MVC solution get new changes from WCF. Namely I dont want to copy-paste all WCF to server after every change. I just send to `ServiceContract.dll` and `Data.dll`.

I dont know how can i do this, how can i separate Dlls and adapt this design to MVC.

Comment: Made code formatting changes

Comment: @RahulGupta `You` formatted `items` as code that actually `are` no `code`.